# Swift Toast message is not display "UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows"

Tags: swift, rootview

i have add one Toast message first time is working Good , but When i use This code in appdelegate file toast message is not working 
Here is my code i am using in app delegate This Code "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" for direct go to this page

```
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

          //  var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! UIViewController

             var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevelControllerNavigation") as! UIViewController

            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

for Toast message i am using this

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.addSubview(self.view)
```

Comment: You cant add a new UIWindow, you have to use the one in the delegate.

Comment: How to use Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You cant add a new UIWindow in ios environment. You have to use the one in the delegate.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController = initialViewController
```